# And operator Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Why does `and` operator returns a value? What is the returned value dependent on?

When I try the following example -

```
(write (and a b c d)) ; prints the greatest integer among a b c d
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are positive integers, then `and` returns the greatest of them.

However when one of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` is 0 or negative, then the smallest integer is returned. Why is this the case?

Comment: When I try your example, I get an error. Are you sure this is a real question?

Comment: I added a extra set of parenthesis around the code. I'm sorry for the error. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_and.htm):

> The macro `and` evaluates each *form* one at a time from left to right. As soon as any form evaluates to `nil`, `and` returns `nil` without evaluating the remaining *forms*. If all *forms* but the last evaluate to `true` values, and returns the results produced by evaluating the last *form*. If no *forms* are supplied, `(and)` returns `t`.

So the returned value doesn't depend on which value is the "greatest" or "smallest" of the arguments.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

`and` can be regarded as a generalization of the two-place `if`. That is to say, `(and a b)` works exactly like `(if a b)`.  With `and` in the place of `if` we can add more conditions: `(and a1 a2 a3 a4 ... aN b)`.  If they all yield true, then `b` is returned.  If we use `if` to express this, it is more verbose, because we still have to use `and`: `(if (and a1 a2 a3 ... aN) b)`. `and` also generalizes in that it can be used with only one argument (`if` cannot), and even with no arguments at all (yields `t` in that case).

Mathematically, `and` forms a group. The identity element of that group is `t`, which is why `(and)` yields `t`.  To describe the behavior of the N-argument `and`, we just need these rules:

```
(and) -> yield t

(and x y) -> { if x is true evaluate and yield y
             { otherwise yield nil
```

Now it turns out that this rule for a two-place `and` obeys the *associative law*: namely `(and (and x y) z)` behaves the same way as `(and x (and y z))`. The effect of the above rules is that no matter in which of these two ways we group the terms in this compound expression, `x`, `y`, and `z` are evaluated from left to right, and evaluation either stops at the first `nil` which it encounters and yields `nil`, or else it evaluates through to the end and yields the value of `z`.

Thus because we have this nice associative property, the rational thing to do in a nice language like Lisp which isn't tied to infix operators is to recognize that since the associative grouping doesn't matter, let's just have the flat syntax `(and x1 x2 x3 ... xN)`, with any number of arguments including zero. This syntax denotes any one of the possible associations of `N-1` binary `and`s which all yield the same behavior.

In other words, let's not make the poor programmer write a nested `(and (and (and ...) ...) ...)` to express a four-term `and`, and just let them write `(and ...)` with four arguments.

Summary:

- the zero-place `and` yields `t`, which has to do with `t` being the identity element for the `and` operation.
- the two-place `and` yields the second value if the first one is true. **This is a useful equivalence to the two-place if**. Binary `and` could be defined as yielding `t` when both arguments are true, but that would be less useful. In Lisp, any value that is not `nil` is a Boolean true. If we replace a non-`nil` value with `t`, it remains Boolean true, but we have lost potentially useful information.
- the behavior of the n-place `and` is a consequence of the associative property; or rather preserving the equivalence between the flat N-argument form and all the possible binary groupings which are already equivalent to each other thanks to the associative property.
- One consequence of all this is that we can have an extended `if`, like `(if cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 ... condN then-form)`, where `then-form` is evaluated and yielded if all the conditions are true. We just have to spell `if` using the `and` symbol.